# SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, xcode, ssl, openssl, exc-bad-access

I recently wanted to build my own client-server system by using BSD sockets. After some point I wanted to include SSL to encrypt the data transfer. I followed [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=22078) tutorial and the code compiles fine with Xcode (added linker flags: -lssl -lcrypto), but I keep getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` all the time once the program reaches the `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file()` call. You can see the used code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SSL_METHOD *method = NULL;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    method = SSLv2_server_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);

    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "/Users/steve/certificate.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "/Users/steve/key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If the program can't find the certificate at the specified path it doesn't crash but I wont have any SSL encryption of course. Could there be a problem with the certificate itself? I simply generated one with openssl by using the following commands:

```
# generate the key
$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024

# generate request
$ openssl req -new -key key.pem -out request.pem
# fill in all the stuff ...

# generate certificate
$ openssl x509 -req -days 30 -in request.pem -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
```

Any idea?

**Update**: There actually are some warnings showing up when compiling with the OS X Deployment Target set to 10.7 or later, because all of this SSL stuff shows up as deprecated. Are there any recommended alternative practices to secure sockets with SSL?

Comment: Your program compile ok (you got some warnings)?

Comment: Got no warnings when setting the OS X Deployment Target to 10.6 or less, because all of this SSL stuff shows up as deprecated in 10.7 or later. Are there any recommended alternative practices to secure sockets with SSL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to call `SSL_library_init`, see the modification inside the code (It's also a good practice to always handle errors from functions that we call :-):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //SSL_METHOD *method = NULL;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    //method = SSLv2_server_method();
    //ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);

    /* Without this line you got an error when calling SSL_CTX_new */
    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_server_method());
    if(!ctx) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "SSL_CTX_new ERROR\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "/Users/steve/certificate.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file ERROR\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "/Users/steve/key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```